# Get Creative soundcard working correctly

Tags: 10.10, sound, alsa, soundcard

I am trying to get sound going on my fresh install of 10.10. 
I have a **creative fatlity** branded sound card. [My ALSA information](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=3ddc0d281e12c64b21461cc9d2453490307fc9b3).

Most things seems to be working out of the box, once I turned off my onboard sound in my BIOS the soundcard kicked in.  However, the system sounds aren't working (I love those drums and the road runner sound when you press backspace).  Also, with a 7.1 setup my center channel and subwoofer don't work at all.  All other channels are working like a champ.

So I am trying to accomplish two things, get system sounds working and get center/sub channels working. How should I try to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux Drivers for Creative Audio Cards

This download is intended for the following audio devices only:

```
* Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Elite Pro 
* Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Platinum
* Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Fatal1ty®
* Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi XtremeGamer
* Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi XtremeMusic
```

1.- Download the driver from [here](http://connect.creativelabs.com/opensource/Wiki/SoundCard%20Support.aspx) (Select Asia, US doesn't work) then select your card and at the bottom of the page change O.S to linux.

2.- compile.

*Notes:*

```
* To install the driver, do the following:
     1. Download the XFiDrv_Linux_US-*.**.tar.gz package onto your local hard disk.
     2. Double-click the downloaded package to unpack its contents.
     3. Read the README file and follow the instructions.
```

if you are going to compile something you need the package `build-essential` we can install with software center or with the follow command in terminal:

> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential

**Update** :

Let's to hack a while !!!!!

download and replace this 2 files in this directory ´XFiDrv_Linux_Public_US_1.00´ :

[ctatc.h](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=6ABAX7UV)

[xfi.c](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=5WPYTJSD)

```
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

and restart....

Comment: @hhlp Thanks for the reply but I am running into issues.  First off when trying the command `sudo aptitude install build-seential` I get an error that says aptitude can't be found.  I tried instead to use `apt-get` and that seemed to work..  Next I get the following error when I try to build the driver http://pastebin.com/34aV878z

Comment: @schwiz you need linux-headers too see my update...

Comment: @hhlp that was a step in the right direction, I am getting one less complaint now :)  http://pastebin.com/2m0eLTVe

Comment: @schwiz see my update...

Comment: @hhlp nice work!  It is compiling now and showing up under my additional drivers as enabled. But, I still don't get a drum beat on my center speaker and sub-woofer. Also, any working system sounds are coming from my left-side speaker and no other speakers.  I am dual booting windows so for a sanity check I did make sure the speakers where working correctly in Windows and they are.

Comment: @schwiz look in sound preference and test the speaker.....

Comment: @hhlp ugh went into alsamixer to find the center speaker was muted by default thanks for all of your help!!

Comment: @schwiz ups!! i forgot that sorry well you're welcome well done

Comment: Can someone post another link to ctatc.h and xfi.c since Megaupload was suddenly shutdown!!! Thanks

Comment: I agree with Kevin, can someone post a link to the ctatc.h and xfi.c files?

Comment: well I think... it's hopeless to ask again for those 2 files 'ctatc.h' and 'xfi.c'